# Limit of an integral and finding the properties of a function which makes the limit of the integral bounded.

Tags: limits

I am realy stuck in solving the following limit problem. 
Can you find any function $g(x)$ by which
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^N}{\log a} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{(1+ag(x))^N}dx = c$$
where $c$ is a nonzero constant.

The solution to this problem may contain some general properties on $g(x)$. But I can't even find a specific $g(x)$ for a specific $N$, say $N=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be rewritten as $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac1{\ln a}\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{e^x~\Big[\frac1a+g(x)\Big]^N}=0\cdot\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{e^x\cdot g(x)^N}=0$, if the latter is convergent. And if it diverges, then we're left with $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac\infty{\ln a}$ , which makes **no** sense at all. So if neither $g(x)$ nor *N* depend on *a*, your problem has no solutions.

Comment: The solution can depend on $N$. @Lucian